# Cannot connect iPhone to my machine as "the host is no longer paired with the device"

Tags: iphone

I am getting the following message from Xcode every time I connect my iPhone to Mac OS X.

> The host is no longer paired with the device.

My iPhone doesn't even charge.

Comment: Is that the exact error message? It doesn't sound like a standard error message.

Comment: Yep ! Boss (@g.)- It's the exact message that I got. The message was from XCode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really, really, really hate to say this; but, in my experience, it works for this kind of thing: Restart your iPhone (home+sleep for a few seconds) and try again.

Comment: Sometimes, restarting the OSX as well will be needed.

Comment: G. - I couldn't believe, It worked. Great. :)

Answer (score 1):

May be it's because you use software such as Parallels Desktop, that hook USB devices, when you plug in...

Comment: Yehh ! But I didn't even install such softwares. I think that iPhone Cable got some problem. I tried with different cable & it worked fine.